# Startup form issue in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

In my [VB.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_.NET) project I have two forms names, `emp` and `admin`. Even if I set the startup form as `emp`, it always loads `admin`. How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Do you have a splash screen defined?

Answer (score 3):

For [Windows Forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Forms) applications, **Go to project in [Solution Explorer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#Other_tools) and find the Windows Form Project, select `Properties -> Application -> Start` Up Form drop down `-> select your startup form*`. Click on the "View Application Events" button to confirm there isn't any startup event code that might re-direct the user to an alternate form.

For [WPF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Presentation_Foundation) applications, **Go to project in solution explorer and find the WPF project, Right Click and `Select Properties -> Application -> Start` Up Form drop down `-> select your startup form*`.

Review Application.xaml to confirm the StartUpURI entry from the Visual Studio project GUI. Click on the "View Application Events" button to confirm there is no code that might re-direct the user to an alternate form.

Answer (score 1):

Go Solutions Explorer.  Click on your project.  Go to project properties.  Look for Startup Form.  Click admin.

Make sure when you build your project, you're not having any compile/build errors.  If you are, it will ask if you want to run the last successful build.  Never answer "Yes" to that question.  Instead, solve your compile errors and run it again.

EDIT: If you've tried it thru setting the startup form and there are no compile errors, then as a last resort, you can try the brute-force method.

1. Create a new static method to your
   project.  Call it, say Startup().

> ```
> Public Sub Startup()
>     admin.Show()
> End Sub
> ```

2. Go to My Project in Solution
   Explorer.
3. On the Application tab, *un*check
   Enable Application Framework.
4. Now in the dropdown above, you'll be
   able to see your Startup() method.
   Choose Startup().
5. Save, build, and run.

You'll see whatever form you want in the code.  This is fool-proof.

Comment: hi Rap,

 Thanks for your answer. While i setting startup form as admin it working. but while i set emp as  startup form it is not working it loads admin.

Comment: hi Rap

  i did not encountered any error while i build my application

Answer (score 0):

If the code in the form emp accesses anything in the admin form (class), it will cause the admin form to be loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Also you should check in My Project properties Application at the bottom that the splash screen is in (None) perhaps you accidentally put the Admin form there.

Answer (score -1):

From project properties, select the startup form. And if it doesn't work, find "application.designer.vb" file.

```
<Global.System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()>  _
        Protected Overrides Sub OnCreateMainForm()
            Me.MainForm = Global.AssemblyExample.<<form name >>
        End Sub
```

`<<form name>>` is the one which you want to set as a startup.

Comment: I don't think editing the Application.Designer.vb file is a very good idea at all. The header clearly states this is a code generated, and "Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if the code is regenerated"